# I am using AWS Cognito Service i am trying to send email when the new user is signup

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito

I am using AWS Cognito Service for authentication i am trying to send email when the new user is signup how can i implement in cognito ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cognito does this automatically if you enable email verification in settings. If you need a welcome message as well, use usersignup lambda trigger and use SES to send them a custom email.

Comment: yes that's correct. But I want know who are all the new user signup that user information should be received to my email

Comment: You can use a post confirmation lambda trigger. Write script to send you an email using SES. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/user-pool-lambda-post-confirmation.html